# Caching Credntials in SVN .subversion/auth directory

Tags: svn, version-control, credentials

What is the format/way to store the username and password in the 'auth' directory so that I dont have to put the username and password each time that I run a SVN command ?
I understand it is not a good practice to store passwords. But still curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have in `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`

```
store-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes
```

(or default commented strings)

and perform any operation with authentication